# A a single-word noun for describing burning love two people have towards each other?

Tags: single-word-requests

Title says all; a burning love between two people. I need a single-word that describes that.

Comment: One single word - passion. Another single word - ardour.

Comment: [Burning Love](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SUC8sdP5eI)...as they say, "He was the King".

Comment: Click the "adoration, love" tab on this page: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/passion

Answer (score 2):

AS Weather Vane suggested:

***ardour*** BrE spelling

***ardor***

> **"heat of passion or desire**," mid-15c., from Old French ardure *"heat, glow; inflammation; passion"* (12c., Modern French ardeur), from Latin ardorem (nominative ardor) "a flame, fire, burning, heat;" also of feelings, etc., "eagerness, zeal," from ardere "to burn," from PIE root *as- "to burn, glow." In Middle English used of base passions; since Milton's time of noble ones.

Sometimes, the best words are the ones usually used.